# Socket.io + Express | io.on('connection' ...) not fired

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I've a little Express-Server and want to fire up some socket.io connection

Here is, what I have on Server-Side:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
});

app.get('/run', function(req, res, next){
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
       socket.on('client_data', function (data) {
          console.log('Message: '+data.message);
       });
    });
});
server.listen(8002, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Here is what I have on client side:

```
<script src="http://host:8002/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect("http://host:8002");
  socket.emit('client_data', {'message': 'hello there!'});
</script>
```

Now, when i go to my browser and type in http://localhost:8002/run it will jump into my "app.get('/run'..)"-Part in my app.js on server ...but unfortunately it will NOT execute io.on('connection'..){}-part and for this reason I will not get the output in my console send from the client. Some Ideas or solution on this issue?

Edit: Ok, it must have something to do with the fact, that my io.on('connection') is running withing the app.get('/run')-Part. Because if i put my io.on('connection')-Part in the server.listen()-Part...it works. Someone any idea why it dosnt work inside?

Comment: try putting these update and give me the resulet :
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use instead of app.all
and finally on client side 
var socket = io.connect();

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found)

Comment: Before the mentioned change, this part worked :)

Comment: for index.html or for socket connection???

Comment: I asked which resource request did respond with 404.

Comment: Ah, the host/socket.io/socket.io.js one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79508/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-blackrafi).

Comment: Still an issue, I've edited my Question with a new fact see "Edit:"